# Ui router browser refresh

Tags: html, angularjs, web-applications, angular-ui-router

I have an Angular 1.x project with the following configuration:

**Html root**:

```
<base href="/admin/" />
<div ui-view="mainView">
```

**State provider config**:

```
config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {
   $stateProvider
        .state('cats_state', {
            url: 'cats',
            views: {
                'mainView': {
                    templateUrl: '/app/components/cats/cats.html'
                }
            }
        })
        .state('dogs_state', {
            url: 'dogs',
            views: {
                'mainView': {
                    templateUrl: '/app/components/dogs/dogs.html'
                }
            }
        })

}])
```

The `cats_state` and `dogs_state` states are associated with urls that are relative to `/admin/` path and they load a specific html template on the same area. When I click on any of them, the browser url is changed to `/admin/cats` and/or `/admin/dogs`. The only issue is: how to reload the same state/template when I manually reload the `/admin/cats` url? I want to achieve this using angular ui-router only, if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While people are viewing this question (but not answering), I have found the solution: and that is to define the

```
<base href="/" />
```

and the urls for various states as:

```
config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {
   $stateProvider
        .state('cats_state', {
            url: '/admin/cats',
            views: {
                'mainView': {
                    templateUrl: '/app/components/cats/cats.html'
                }
            }
        })
        .state('dogs_state', {
            url: '/admin/dogs',
            views: {
                'mainView': {
                    templateUrl: '/app/components/dogs/dogs.html'
                }
            }
        })

}])
```

I didn't quite understood why this is happening, but it works like this. Also, I have noticed that the / path is reloaded first (and therefore all dependencies), and after this, the ui-router somehow resolves the current url, probably based on the states configuration as being the one from the browser's address.